# Gradle 1.5 cannot exclude more than one dependency in compile

Tags: gradle, guava, build.gradle, activejdbc

For compatibility reasons, I have to use gradle 1.5, and when I try to do

```
compile('org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.9') { 
        exclude group: "com.google.collections", module: "google-collections"
        exclude group: "com.google.code.google-collections", module: "google-collect"
    }
```

in my build.gradle, only the first item com.google.collections is excluded, but the second com.google.code.google-collections is not excluded. It seems like a bug with Gradle 1.5? Does anyone know a workaround for this? I've been trying for days and I'm dying here.

Thanks a bunch for helping out!!! :)

Comment: Are you sure the `com.google.code` dependency isn't being pulled in transitively from another place than this one?

Comment: I think so because if I don't include activejdbc-instrumentation, I don't encounter any google-collections errors at all. Do you know how I might counter this issue? thanks!

Comment: just to be sure, the instrumentation plugin should not be on a compile  classpath. It is used in a post-comlile step, called ... instrumentation. Whatever dependency it uses will then not be on the classpath of your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found out why, with help from @ipolevoy. I think Gradle 1.5 has the bug that doesn't exclude the second package you list. For this particular problem, since the instrumentation plugin didn't need to be compiled, I just had to include it as a classpath in Gradle's buildscript, and then import it for use as a post-compile task.